# no "new android project", but have others like "android sample project" etc

Tags: android

I'm using Eclipse, the ADT plugin and the Android SDK. I've been following the guide on developer.android.com but I can't seem to find the "new android project". I've done the guide multiple times, reinstalling eclipse and the plugin and the SDK etc.

If I click "new project" in eclipse I find an Android folder there, which when expanded, shows the following options:

Android Application Project
Android Project from Existing Code
Android Sample Project
Android Test Project

Any ideas on what's wrong? Why can't I find "new android project" ?

Answer (score 3):

i think you use new ADT `ADT 20` and its have `Android Application Project`.

`Android Application Project` is your `new android project` in `ADT 20.`

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that will be fixed in the next release. For now, you can try:

Window->Preferences->Android

There, check if your Android SDK path is set correctly. If you still have the issue, try this work around:

- Delete the support library from the SDK manager
- Create a new project & install the support library by clicking on "Install / Upgrade".

Comment: I'm pretty sure the path is correct, so what kind of project should I create if I want to try the workaround?